# Referencing Choice Field in Calculated Columns

Tags: list, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

I have a question regarding Calculated Columns.

I have a Column Called "NextMileStone", this column can contain "PM010", "PM020, "PM040", "PM070", or some other choices that would be the "else" choice in my if Statement. Then I have a column for each of the previously mentioned "PMs", these contain a date.

Now I want to create a calculated Column, called "Date Next Milestone", that should ideally fetch the date from the "PM" columns, based on which PM is set as the Next Milestone in "NextMileStone".

I created the following formula to do this:

```
"=IF([NextMilestone]="PM010",[PM010 Date],IF([NextMilestone]="PM020",[PM020 Date],IF([NextMilestone]="PM040",[PM040 Date],IF([NextMilestone]="PM070",[PM070 Date],DATE(2000,1,1)))))"
```

However, sharepoint always gives me a syntax Error. (Disregard the "else" choice that I set to first of January 2000 for now, I tried different values and I don't think the error lies in the else choice)

I suspect that this happens because I cannot reference the value of a choice field as a string.
My question is, how do I reference the value of a choice field in a formula?

Comment: Your column name is "NextMileStone" whereas in formula you have referred as "Next MileStone". Please correct the question for correct column name.

Comment: I have fixed it, thank you for your comment. I have filled in the name of the column via the function to directly add in columns in the sharepoint Calculated Column Creation mask, so that was (unfortunately) not the problem, I still edited the question to make it more clear.

Comment: in the formula, put only column value "[NextMilestone]" and see the output. Choice column value does work with calculated columns

Comment: Well then maybe it doesn't work in IF statements? Because I am basically comparing a choice to a string in my IF statement, right?

Answer (score 0):

I am swiss, and in Switzerland, you need to use **";"** instead of **","**, because the comma is reserved for numbers...

Answer (score 0):

Choice and Lookup Columns save the values not in plain text, think of it as an array.
You need to compare the IDs of the items.

Comment: It (apparently) does work with string comparison though, because my formula works after I replaced the commas with semi-colons.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change the position of the `""` and it should be like this instead:

```
=IF([NextMilestone]=PM010,"PM010 Date").
```

You can also check reference:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/if-function-7025be14-5665-43d0-af20-8293d1fe9d3a